# Implementation of Execv() instead of execvp()

Tags: c, linux, shell, exec

I want to learn how to implement execv() instead of execvp()

I have the code which has execvp() and i try to convert it into execv() but i failed because i couldn't find the path of the commands.
Which command gets the path of the file i think but how can i implement it onto execv()

I want to convert this code:

```
if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {     /* fork a child process           */
        printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
        exit(1);
}
else if (pid == 0) {          /* for the child process:         */
    printf("hophop");
    if (execv("/usr/bin/ls"+*args[0], args) < 0) {     /* execute the command  */
        printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
else {                                  /* for the parent:      */
    while (wait(&status) != pid)       /* wait for completion  */
        ;
}
/** the steps are:
     (1) fork a child process using fork()
     (2) the child process will invoke execvp()
     (3) if background == 0, the parent will wait,
     otherwise it will invoke the setup() function again. */
```

Comment: this line: 'while (wait(&status) != pid)' should be: 'wait(&status);'

Comment: Are you sure the `ls` binary is located in `/usr/bin/` on your system ? What does `which ls` say ?

Comment: this line: 'if (execv("/usr/bin/ls"+*args[0], args) < 0) {' does not send the correct format to execv().  any parameters to the ls command must be in the args, where args is defined something like: char** args[]; and the last entry in that array must be a NULL

Comment: What on earth is `"/usr/bin/ls"+*args[0]` supposed to mean? `*args[0]` is probably the first letter in the name of your executable, you're going to be adding the character code of that to address of the string literal `"/usr/bin/ls"`, doing some pointer arithmetic, going way past the end of that string, and ending up sending some really weird data to `execv()`.

Answer (score 2):

execvp searches for the command in the list of the directories in the PATH environment variable.

If you want to duplicate the functionality of execvp, getenv("PATH"), split the string into the individual directories (colon-delimited string), then search each directory in the list until you find your executable, and the execv() it.

If you have an executable filename that's already an absolute path starting with the / character, skip the searching part, of course; in this case execvp is equivalent to execv.